# Magento override Catalog Compare controller doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers, compare

for some reason the Compare controller override doesn't work for me, I tried about everything I could find, but it just doesn't happen and I am running out of ideas. Do you see anything I am doing wrong?

**etc/modules/Unirack_CatalogExtended.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unirack_CatalogExtended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Unirack_CatalogExtended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

(but I see the module in Admin > Configuration > Advanced, so I reckon it is registered correctly)

**code/local/Unirack/CatalogExtended/etc/config.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unirack_CatalogExtended>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Unirack_CatalogExtended>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalog>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Unirack_CatalogExtended before="Mage_Catalog">Unirack_CatalogExtended</Unirack_CatalogExtended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**code/local/Unirack/CatalogExtended/controllers/Product/CompareController.php** :

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'Product'.DS.'CompareController.php';

class Unirack_CatalogExtended_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('overriden'); // never happens
    }
}
```

Even if I put `die();` statement at the beginning of my custom `CompareController.php`, it doesn't happen, the file is just not loaded at all. So I reckon it must be somewhere in the config.xml where I register it, or in paths structure, but I've already checked all this several times and just cannot find anything. Sometimes Magento can really be frustrating  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good, except `<codepool>local</codepool>` should be `<codePool>local</codePool>`

Comment: You are my hero, indeed that was it, thanks a lot. Still I don't get why is Magento so sensitive about case in XMLs.. well I will certainly remember this one.